# How to fill an angular material datatable with data from a json?

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material, angular-datatables

I have a project in angular, and have an angular material datatable. So, I want to fill it with data from a json. Because when I try to fill it simply nothing is showed, as if empty, but if I fill the datatable with static data, it shows the data. The idea is filling the datatable with data from json.

Comment: do you have any snippet? or fiddle?

Comment: try making array from that json, and pass it to datatable.

Comment: Show us your json so that we can help you!

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to instantiate `MatTableDataSource` with the data that you get from your service.

```
dataSource;
data;

ngOnInit() {
  this.yourService.getData()
    .subscribe((data: Type[]) => {
      this.data = data;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
    });
}
```

And then in your template, use this:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  ...
</table>
```

Note here that the responsibility of getting the data from the backend is of the Service and you'll just call a method on it to get the data.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-modal?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.component.ts) for your ref. In here, I'm getting the users list from JSONPlaceholder API and then showing it on the template by setting its `dataSource`

Answer (score 1):

Please check this, hope it will help you:

```
this.http.get('servieurl').subscribe(data => 
{
 this.apps.push(data);
 this.displayedColumns = ['columnName'];
 this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.apps);
 }, error => console.error(error));
```

Html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
 ...
</table>
```

For more check this link : [fill an angular material datatable with data from a json?](https://therichpost.com/angular-material-datatables-example-with-laravel-5-6-api-data)